# New to python: is this indexing and slicing?

Tags: python

new to python. Learn indexing and slicing. what does it mean.

```
for i in range (len(number)):
    if(number[-i-1]=='0'):
```

i don't understand this [-i-1]

Comment: The expression `-i -1` evaluates to a single number, given `i` is produced from `range`. The first iteration will have `i` as `0`, so it would result in accessing `number[-1]` when put together.  This `for` loop looks to be accessing the list of `number` in reverse, as the subsequent iteration, it would be `-1 -1`, or `-2`.  In any case, please refer to [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) as indexing is can be thought of as a subset of slicing in Python.

Comment: @metatoaster mmm or the other way around. `seq[whatever]` is *indexing*, if you pass a `slice` object as `whatever` that is a *slicing*. But I can see what you are saying.

Comment: Yeah, oops, I meant the other way around.  Thanks for the correction.  To recap, `slice` is basically a special type of index that can be passed to a list to return a segment of the list.

Answer (score 1):

the number I'm assuming is a list of numbers eg. [0,1,2,3,4]

the number[-i-1] refers to the number at the index of -i-1 (indexing)

for example when i = 0, -i-1 = -1, which in python means the last index or 1 from the back

which in my example would be 4

Slicing would be like numbers[2:4], which will return a portion of the array of [2,3]

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing is indexing
say your array is

```
number=[2,4,6,8,10]
number[0] is 2
number[-1] is 10
```

So, If you want to get the **ith** number from front the indexing is

```
number[i]
```

If you want to get the **ith** number from rear,which is your case then the indexing looks like

```
number[-i-1]
```

Just for your information slicing is used to get a part of the sequence in the array

```
number[1:4] gives [4,6,8] 
number[:4] gives [2,4,6,8]
number[4:] gives [10]
```

Hope this helps